# Overwriting lines in file in C

Tags: c, file, line, overwrite

I'm doing a project on filesystems on a university operating systems course, my C program should simulate a simple filesystem in a human-readable file, so the file should be based on lines, a line will be a "sector". I've learned, that lines must be of the same length to be overwritten, so I'll pad them with ascii zeroes till the end of the line and leave a certain amount of lines of ascii zeroes that can be filled later.

Now I'm making a test program to see if it works like I want it to, but it doesnt. The critical part of my code:

```
file = fopen("irasproba_tesztfajl.txt", "r+"); //it is previously loaded with 10 copies of the line I'll print later in reverse order  

  /* this finds the 3rd line */
 int count = 0; //how much have we gone yet?
 char c;

 while(count != 2) {
  if((c = fgetc(file)) == '\n') count++;
 }

 fflush(file);

 fprintf(file, "- . , M N B V C X Y Í Ű Á É L K J H G F D S A Ú Ő P O I U Z T R E W Q Ó Ü Ö 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0\n");

 fflush(file);

 fclose(file);
```

Now it does nothing, the file stays the same. What could be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe a before and after sample of what the file looks like would help us help you?

Comment: You're not doing any error checking here. Are you sure the file actually got opened successfully?

Comment: If your lines are a fixed length then you should be able to skip to a sector using fseek() instead of reading each character. -- fseek(file, (bytes_per_line + 1) * line_number, SEEK_SET);

Comment: @Alexandre Jasmin: I meant NUL characters, they don't show up in most editors or show as whitespaces and also they'll be on the right after a terminating character, so they won't bother anybody

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [here](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/nsc/lib/fopen.html),

> When a file is opened with a "+"
>   option, you may both read and write on
>   it. However, you may not perform an
>   output operation immediately after an
>   input operation; you must perform an
>   intervening "rewind" or "fseek".
>   Similarly, you may not perform an
>   input operation immediately after an
>   output operation; you must perform an
>   intervening "rewind" or "fseek".

So you've achieved that with `fflush`, but in order to write to the desired location you need to `fseek` back. This is how I implemented it - could be better I guess:

```
 /* this finds the 3rd line */
 int count = 0; //how much have we gone yet?
 char c;
 int position_in_file;

 while(count != 2) {
  if((c = fgetc(file)) == '\n') count++;
 }

 // Store the position
 position_in_file = ftell(file);
 // Reposition it
 fseek(file,position_in_file,SEEK_SET); // Or fseek(file,ftell(file),SEEK_SET);

 fprintf(file, "- . , M N B V C X Y Í Ű Á É L K J H G F D S A Ú Ő P O I U Z T R E W Q Ó Ü Ö 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0\n");  
 fclose(file);
```

Also, as has been commented, you should check if your file has been opened successfully, i.e. before reading/writing to `file`, check:

```
file = fopen("irasproba_tesztfajl.txt", "r+");
if(file == NULL)
{
  printf("Unable to open file!");
  exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Correct.  ANSI C requires that a file positioning function intervene between output and input, unless an input operation encounters end-of-file.

Comment: I know nothing about this subject, but wouldn't such a requirement cause slower IO access? A call to "pad" between calls that could otherwise be avoided takes processing time.  Just asking.

Comment: It works now, thanks :)

As for the error checking, as I said, this is only a test program to see how things work, so I leave the error checking for the final version